# how to replaceOne document in MongoDb with Mongo database command

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

We have requirement to execute [replaceOne](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) operation with [db.runCommand()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.runCommand/)

I checked list of commands from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/command/), but i haven't found any command to replace one document.

Can someone please suggest us whether this is possible or not?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/command/update/#dbcmd.update

Answer (score 0):

We can use update command to replace one document. Refer [update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/command/update/#update-with-a-replacement-document) for more details.

**Sample replace command**

```
{
    'update': 'collectionName',
    'updates': [
        {
            'q': {
                'age': '33'
            },
            'u': {
                'status': 'pass',
                'company': 'AK'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Refer [update-with-a-replacement-document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/command/update/#update-with-a-replacement-document) for more details